# Overriding private method of Model file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, override-model

I am overriding private method of model file of checkout module

below is my di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Vendor\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" />
```

An here is my model file.

```
 use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
 class DefaultConfigProvider extends 
 \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{
  protected $customerRepository;
  public function __construct(
   CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
   ) {
     $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}
 private function getCustomerData()
  {
    $customerData = [];
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());
        $customerMasterId = $customer->getMasterId();
        $masterCustomer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerMasterId);
        $customerData = $customer->__toArray();
        foreach ($masterCustomer->getAddresses() as $key => $address) {
            $customerData['addresses'][$key]['inline'] = $this->getCustomerAddressInline($address);
        }
     }
     return $customerData;
  }

}
```

I am not able to override this function since it is private, I did research an found that we need to use plugin method for it, but not found which plugin and how to use in this scenario.

All i am looking is master customer have address so i need to read address from master customer instead of logged customer.

Please anyone suggest me how can i override that method to add my custom logic inside. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A plugin can be used in public functions only.

Comment: so we can override private functions into custom modules?

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice that it is a private function. :)

Comment: yes, how can i achieve above functionality?

Comment: Wait. I am updating the answer.

Comment: @jafarpinjar please check my answer. may it can help you

Comment: @jafarpinjar I have added my answer with plugin method. Please check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Private function is not override:

so you have better option that you can override *getConfig* method of
**Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider**

and use

> di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="plugin_getconfig" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\DefaultConfigProvider" />
    </type>
</config>
```

---

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\DefaultConfigProvider

```php
private function getcustomCustomerData()
{
    $customerData = [];
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());
        $customerMasterId = $customer->getMasterId();
        $masterCustomer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerMasterId);
        $customerData = $customer->__toArray();
        foreach ($masterCustomer->getAddresses() as $key => $address) 
        {
            $customerData['addresses'][$key]['inline'] = $this->getCustomerAddressInline($address);
        }
    }
    return $customerData;
}
```

---

```php
public function aftergetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $result){
    $output['customerData'] =  ***$this->getcustomCustomerData();***
      
    return $output;
}
```

make **getcustomCustomerData()** method what you want to add logic add over here

Comment: hi @Rutvee, i am not cleared about your answer, can you please update me code, as per my question issue

Comment: @jafarpinjar   You are trying to override getCustomerData method but it's private so you have to override getConfig() method and   $output['customerData'] =  ***$this->getcustomCustomerData();*** and use her custom method instead of getCustomerData

Comment: hi @Rutvee, got something now, but what are the code changes i need to do in my di.xml as well as model file please

Comment: @jafarpinjar you have already write in your di.xml <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Vendor\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" /> so no need any change overther

Comment: @jafarpinjar just add above code in your Vendor\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider

Comment: @jafarpinjar i have edited my answer please check

Comment: Sure, @Rutvee, i will check and confirm you

Comment: can i use only $output['customerData'] =  $this->getcustomCustomerData(); 
 instead of all other functions? because all other functions also private

Comment: I am getting below error,
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFormKey()  on null, since that method is private

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84228/discussion-between-rutvee-sojitra-and-jafar-pinjar).

Comment: @jafarpinjar please check updated answer

Answer (score 5):

Instead of overriding **getCustomerData** function, create a plugin for **getConfig** function.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="customize_defaultconfig" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\DefaultConfigProvider" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/DefaultConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $result['customerData'] = $this->getCustomerData();
        return $result;
    }

}


public function getCustomerData()
{
    $customerData = [];
    // Get the current customer id here and add your logic.
    return $customerData;
}
```

Comment: hi @Dinesh, I want to add logic for customerData,  please check my question

Comment: Yes but eventually it is going to be used in getConfig function. So you can add your logic here.

Comment: yes @Dinesh, but customerData, is empty now, because no customer have address, but his parent have address, so i need to alter the logic for customerData,

Comment: So you can just empty the variable $result['customerData']; and then add your custom function in this plugin and add your logic for customer address in that function. Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't override private method in child class.

But you can override public method then call it to your custom private method.

```
private function _customGetCustomerData() {
    $customerData = [];
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());
        $customerMasterId = $customer->getMasterId();
        $masterCustomer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerMasterId);
        $customerData = $customer->__toArray();
        foreach ($masterCustomer->getAddresses() as $key => $address) {
            $customerData['addresses'][$key]['inline'] = $this->getCustomerAddressInline($address);
        }
    }
    return $customerData;
}
```

Then override `getConfig` function, inside that function call to your custom function instead of `$output['customerData'] = $this->getCustomerData();`

```
public function getConfig() {
    $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
    $output['formKey'] = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    $output['customerData'] = $this->_customGetCustomerData(); // use your function instead
    $output['quoteData'] = $this->getQuoteData();
    $output['quoteItemData'] = $this->getQuoteItemData();
    $output['isCustomerLoggedIn'] = $this->isCustomerLoggedIn();
    $output['selectedShippingMethod'] = $this->getSelectedShippingMethod();
    $output['storeCode'] = $this->getStoreCode();
    $output['isGuestCheckoutAllowed'] = $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed();
    $output['registerUrl'] = $this->getRegisterUrl();
    $output['checkoutUrl'] = $this->getCheckoutUrl();
    $output['defaultSuccessPageUrl'] = $this->getDefaultSuccessPageUrl();
    $output['pageNotFoundUrl'] = $this->pageNotFoundUrl();
    $output['forgotPasswordUrl'] = $this->getForgotPasswordUrl();
    $output['staticBaseUrl'] = $this->getStaticBaseUrl();
    $output['priceFormat'] = $this->localeFormat->getPriceFormat(
        null,
        $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getQuoteCurrencyCode()
    );
    $output['basePriceFormat'] = $this->localeFormat->getPriceFormat(
        null,
        $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getBaseCurrencyCode()
    );
    $output['postCodes'] = $this->postCodesConfig->getPostCodes();
    $output['imageData'] = $this->imageProvider->getImages($quoteId);
    $output['totalsData'] = $this->getTotalsData();
    $output['shippingPolicy'] = [
        'isEnabled' => $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'shipping/shipping_policy/enable_shipping_policy',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ),
        'shippingPolicyContent' => nl2br(
            $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                'shipping/shipping_policy/shipping_policy_content',
                ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )
    ];
    $output['activeCarriers'] = $this->getActiveCarriers();
    $output['originCountryCode'] = $this->getOriginCountryCode();
    $output['paymentMethods'] = $this->getPaymentMethods();
    $output['autocomplete'] = $this->isAutocompleteEnabled();
    $output['displayBillingOnPaymentMethod'] = $this->checkoutHelper->isDisplayBillingOnPaymentMethodAvailable();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Please update me code,  how can i override as per my question issue?

Comment: updated code above